# Stop java program in background

Tags: java, keyevent

I have a java program that is running in the background(Windows). I would like to bind a key that will terminate the process in some way, even if you are currently working in another program. Is this possible?

Basically I would like to do something like:

```
If(KeyPressed)
//break from main loop;
```

Comment: something like `System.exit(0);` ??

Comment: yes, but who does he know when to call that? Please re-read the question. @manurajhada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to use JNI. I've used this with some success:
http://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/

Answer (score 1):

Check out Java Com api to bind your program to Windows COM ports to listen to keypress actions

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/javacomm/reference/api/javax/comm/package-summary.html

http://users.frii.com/jarvi/rxtx/

Also try this tutorial for accessing windows hardware (ie keyboard)
http://beqi.com/beqi/java_com_accessing_windows_hardware.php

Comment: JNI is another option, but it is harder to use since you do need to know a bit of C to write bits that communicate with hardware most of the time